# SOAPUI: can't get tag's value from xml in data source step by data source loop from soap responce

Tags: xml, soap, soapui, ready-api

I have an issue with SOAPUI, i get xml with a few word's errors from YandexSpeller. 
xml that i have got here: https://pastebin.com/0E44WH2a

```
<SpellResult>
           <error code="1" pos="1" row="0" col="1" len="6">
              <word>beautoful</word>
              <s>beautiful</s>
           </error>
           <error code="1" pos="9" row="0" col="9" len="10">
              <word>lidy</word>
              <s>lady</s>
           </error>
           <error code="1" pos="20" row="0" col="20" len="7">
              <word>cemmon</word>
              <s>common</s>
           </error>
```

I want to get each error in data source loop and save it to excel-file. There is problem that i can get attributes "len" and "pos" from error tag by @len and @pos, but can't get text from "word" and "s" child tags. 
There is example of ready-api error:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrRd0.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's started to work for me when i add tag "ns1:" (that i declared higher in "row xpath" block) to "word" and "s" in "column xpath" block.

```
ns1:word/text()
ns1:s/text()
```